# Pure Javascript - Click and scroll to Div inside div

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML, with scrollbar:

```
<div id="parent">
      <div id="child1">Something</div>
      <div id="child2">Something</div>
      <div id="child3">Something</div>
      <div id="child4">Something</div>
      <div id="child5">Something</div>
      <div id="child6">Something</div>
      <div id="child7">Something</div>
      <div id="child8">Something</div>
      <div id="child9">Something</div>   
</div>
```

My question is this:

How can I, in pure javascript, position the scroll of the div 'parent' in one of the childs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) function of JavaScript like this:

```
document.getElementById('child9').scrollIntoView()
```

[Try it online](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_scrollintoview)

Comment: Oh, so simple and works! Was not aware of the scrollIntoView method. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Mike This function is not scrolling horizontally. Is there a way to do the same thing horizontally as well?

Comment: @jitendragarg I agree that if you leave some of the div on the scrollable area it doesn't scroll horizontally although i can't find any way around it